# Creating a utility network

Tags: arcgis-pro, utility-network

I want to create a utility network in ArcGIS Pro. I am using the Create Utility Network tool and the tool wants me to Specify a polygon feature class that is necessarily Z- and M- enabled for the Service Territory Feature Class parameter. I have no idea about that. How can I do this??

Answer (score 1):

The [Create Utility Network (Utility Network)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/utility-networks/create-utility-network.htm) documentation says in its **Summary**:

> Creates a utility network in an enterprise, file, or mobile
> geodatabase feature dataset.
>
> A utility network is created and a structure network, with its
> collection of feature classes, is added to the target feature dataset.

Then in its **Usage**:

> The **Service Territory Feature Class** parameter value must exist in
> the input feature dataset and must be z- and m-enabled.

Then in its **Parameters** section that the `service_territory_feature_class` is:

> The existing polygon feature class that will be used to create the
> utility network's geographical extent. Utility network features cannot
> be created outside of this extent.
>
> The feature class must be z- and m-enabled.

The z- and m-enabled polygon feature class that you wish use to create your utility network's geographical extent is something that you will need to identify and/or prepare from amongst the datasets that you are planning to use to create your utility network.

If you are new to creating a utility network then you may wish to go through the [Get started with a utility network in ArcGIS](https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/get-started-with-the-arcgis-utility-network/get-started-with-the-utility-network.htm) tutorial.